# Fiddler cannot find revocation server

Tags: fiddler

I am getting the a popup message every 20 times a minute saying:

**it was not possible to connect to the revocation server or a definitive response could not be obtained**

I am using fiddler classic version:

v5.0.20204.45441 for .NET 4.6.1

We are on a very locked down network, so I am looking for work arounds, not blaming Teleric or Fiddler.